# Google map clustering is slow in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Are there any alternatives to implement clustering for over 15K marker on the maps. I've used google maps api 2 with extensions for clustering, but still got the problem when zoom (it thinks too much before unclustering items), i think that it's due to slow map marker initialization.

Comment: With so many points you should probably define a minimum zoom level so that user can only see, say, one US state at a time (if your map spans the whole world). He can zoom in, but not zoom out. This way you can query and load only the visible markers and get rid of the rest of the world (but refresh your query if the user pans outside).

Comment: Do you need the markers to dynamically cluster/uncluster during the zoom animation? Or only once the camera has settled again